# Using selenium to click search button

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to click the search button in this link [here](https://publicaccess.aberdeencity.gov.uk/online-applications/search.do?action=weeklyList)

I would like to click the search button and then download all URL's on the next page but currently it is finding monthly list

The link below takes you to a screenshot of my code where it outputs the monthly list button instead of searcj/

[Python code selenium](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bqYQa.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow!

You can use the `.click()` method to click an element object, and the `.find_element_by_xpath()` method to find the element. I've located that the element's full XPATH is `/html/body/div/div/div[3]/div[3]/div/form/fieldset/div[5]/input[2]`.

You can implement all the pieces together like so:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div/div[3]/div[3]/div/form/fieldset/div[5]/input[2]").click()
```

Comment: Thanks @Xiddoc, If I was to download all URL's on the page after once I have pressed the search button do I use something like this 
test = driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME,"a")
print(test)

When I use this I get a session id and not a URL. Sorry for extending the question

Answer (score 0):

if you are starting I recommend you using some extension to help you find the xPath of the elements.
I used Xpath Helper from Chrome, but you can use any other.

The Xpath of the Search button is:

```
/html[@class='js']/body/div[@id='idox']/div[@id='pa']/div[@class='container'][2]/div[@class='content']/div[@class='tabcontainer']/form[@id='weeklyListForm']/fieldset/div[@class='buttons']/input[@class='button primary']
```

After you have the XPath you can use it in the selenium driver to find the elements.

This can be enough, but I recommend you to learn in depth how this works to know exactly what it is doing.